# Rails 5 How to upload generated csv (carrierwave)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, file-upload, carrierwave

In my app I want to upload `.csv` files to cloud using carrierwave, but before I want to test uploader local, but I don't know how to upload generated in app `csv string`. In my app it looks like that:

`/uploaders/file_uploader.rb`

```
class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
 # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
 storage :file

 # define some uploader specific configurations in the initializer
 # to override the global configuration

 def store_dir
   "uploads/#{model.id}"
 end
end
```

`/models/rooms.rb`

```
class Rooms < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :file, FileUploader

end
```

`/services/generate_csv`

```
require 'csv'

class GenerateCsv

  def initialize(room)
    @room = room
  end

  def build
   csv_string = gen_csv
   @room.file = csv_string
   @room.save!
  end

  def gen_csv
    CSV.generate do |csv|
      csv << headers

      users.each do |user|
        csv << GenerateRow.gen(room: @room)
      end
    end
  end

end
```

And it doesn't work. After `room.save!` column file is `nil`. Is there any option to upload generated `csv` and associate to DB column (after all I only need `URL` to download)? Maybe I should create `csv file` instead of `csv string`? Can you help me with tihs?

@EDIT

### **Solution**

`/services/generate_csv`

```
...
  def build
   csv_string = gen_csv
   @room.file = StringIO.new(csv_string)
   @room.save!
  end
...
```